# Using the current resource to simplify code in controller for Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise for user authentication, and am overwriting/modifying the create action on the registrations controller, however, it is in danger of becoming quite verbose, and repeating myself too much. I am creating an app where the user can set a keyholder for their account, who has certain privileges, and a guest, who has read-only access.

What I'm trying to achieve is to use the 'resource' object within the create method, as opposed to specifying whether I'm referring to a guest or keyholder. For example, checking whether the user already has a keyholder or guest for their account (they're only allowed one).

I.e. instead of something along the lines of:

```
if @user.keyholder_id
  # don't create keyholder
end
```

and

```
if @user.guest_id
  # don't create guest 
end
```

is it possible to use the current resource_name, e.g.:

```
if @user.{resource_name}_id.nil?
  # create resource in question
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
@user.read_attribute("#{resource_name}_id").nil?
```

to set attribute dinamically, you use:

```
@user.update_attribute("#{resource_name}_id", resource.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for that - what if I am trying to update the current_user's guest_id for example? Previously I would have done this with @user.guest_id = resource.id - however the read_attribute throws a syntax error when used in this way. Thanks!

Comment: That's great, just what I needed, thanks! What's the difference between write_attribute and update_attribute, or does it not matter in this case?

Comment: @ecs `write_attribute` does not save your record. BTW I'm not sure if this method is still in Rails 3.2 and Rails 4.0.

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.0 and have tested the code on my development server and it seems to be working. Thanks again.